# Javascript: cannot replace two double quotes with a single doublequote

Tags: javascript

`value` is `"//a[@class="post-tag"]"` and I am trying to remove the two double quotes from the `jsonString` which returns `""//a[@class=\"post-tag\"]""`

```
                            var jsonString = JSON.stringify(value);
                            var cleanjson = jsonString.replace(/""/g, '"');
```

I don't understand why this simple example is not working. `jsonString` returns `""//a[@class=\"post-tag\"]""` and I am trying to replace the two doublequotes with a single one. However, `cleanjson` will still have the two double quotes.

Comment: I think the `"`s on the edges might be string delimiters, not actual parts of the string

Comment: May I ask why you are doing `JSON.stringify` in the first place? That is what is producing these double doublequotes. Why can't you just use `value` and get rid of the 2 lines of code you have here?

Comment: You can do jsonString.split('').shift().join('').

Comment: @blex basically I need to escape xpaths with double quotes inside it, so i was being lazy and thought of using `JSON.stringify` to escape them and thought I could remove it naturally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be simpler to trim the outer quotes before stringifying it:

```js
var value = '"//a[@class="post-tag"]"';

// Remove quotes at the beginning and end
var trimmed = value.replace(/(^"|"$)/g, '');
console.log(trimmed);    // -> //a[@class="post-tag"]

// Escape remaining quotes and add outer quotes back
var escaped = JSON.stringify(trimmed);
console.log(escaped);    // -> "//a[@class=\"post-tag\"]"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove the two double quotes because they aren't present in your variable

The value of the `jsonString` variable is `"//a[@class="post-tag"]"`, but because it is a string, it will be displayed encapsulated in double quotes: `""//a[@class="post-tag"]""`